# How to darken the underneath of an element?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to show a `div` element having a `z-index` 1050. So I want to make an appearance of darkness for all the elements beneath it ; something like in this image :

[image]

Here is the `div` element I want to show :

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dlg" data-close-button="true" data-windows-style="true" data-overlay="true" data-overlay-color="op-dark" style="position: fixed;float: left;z-index: 1050;left: 0px;right: 0px;top: 310px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">
    <div class="container">
        <h2><?php echo _getText('global.dialog.titre.conf'); ?></h2>
        <p>
            <span id="dlg_msg"></span><span class="place-right"><button id="dlg_oui" class="button default" style="margin-right: 5px;"><?php echo _getText('global.oui'); ?></button><button id="dlg_non" class="button default"><?php echo _getText('global.non'); ?></button></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how to make the darkness when the `div` is showing ?

Comment: Well, basically you could do that by having a div occupy the whole page, with a lesser z-index than the one you want to show above, and give it a black color with `opacity: 0` normally and when your div is to show, change the opacity of the other div to 0.5, for example. Or have a hidden div that occupies the whole page and show it only when your "upper" div is shown

Comment: use an overlay with z-index : 1049, and semi transparent background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you tried searching for this up front and could not find it: The term you should search for is a **Modal**, a sort of in-browser pop-up that is usually accompanied by a faded background.

A very nice explanation with variations of how to achieve that is given here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/

Basically, you have a div:

```
    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

And you give it a background that is somewhat transparent and has a dark color, maybe just black. Also make sure it spans the entire page:

```
    .overlay{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
    }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of code and do not just add a link.

Comment: the "fixed" method is the best among the other proposed methods :)

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference would be to create a semitransparent overlay image (PNG/GIF). So for example, create a 5x5 pixel GIF/PNG with a solid colour of black. Then give it a transparency of 50%.

Then use something like this CSS Class...

```
.hidescreen 
    {
        position:fixed;
        display:block;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:499;
        background: url('./Images/translucent-background.png') repeat; /* This ensures the translucent background works in IE. */
    }
```

I prefer this method as it works in pretty much all browsers, including old IE.

Comment: i am interested in this approach. So before this one is hidden?then when the alert for example is available you set it to visible?

Comment: A very vanilla way of doing it is simply to add it as a div. Say... <div id="#overlay"></div> and then use jQuery to add the class. $("#overlay").addClass(".hidescreen");

Answer (score 1):

One option, having put your modal in place is just to give it a massive `box-shadow`.

Since this does not increase the element size it does not cause overflow.

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9999px 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem dolore veritatis sint totam, unde repellendus tenetur ratione consectetur soluta nihil nobis nulla fugiat molestiae deserunt accusantium vitae eaque temporibus, aliquid quis. Aut hic itaque
  iste eligendi ipsa</div>

<div class="modal">
  <h1>Top of the World, Ma! Top of the World</h1>
</div>
```